# Saving string on orientation change FC's app if changed too quickly

Tags: android, orientation, savestate, android-dialog

I'm having trouble saving a string on orientation changed.  I've tried using `onSaveInstanceState()/onRestoreInstanceState()` and `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()/getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` with no luck.

I have:

```
@Override
public String onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(){
    final String savedType = currentType;
    return savedType;
}
```

and in `onCreate()` I have:

```
currentType = (String) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
```

This hasn't worked for me yet and `currentType` is always `null` after an orientation change.  Any suggestions?

---

### Revision

---

So this is what I currently have and it's still not working:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    outState.putString("savedType", currentType);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    currentType = savedInstanceState.getString("savedType");
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I've tried putting the `super` method calls at the beginning and end of each method in every combination I could think of but am still getting a `NullPointerException` for `currentType` when the view is created again.

---

### Also

---

This is happening in a Dialog, I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it but thought that might be a useful bit of info.

---

---

### Partial Solution/Partial New Question

---

---

So I got this working somewhat like I wanted.  There was a statement buried in a method that set `currentType` to `null` towards the end of the life cycle when the variable wouldn't be needed again.  That's now out of the way.  The screen will successfully change orientations but if it's changed between the two successively too quickly it will FC.  This is what I used to get it working in this state:

Class Field:

```
private String currentType;
```

At the end of `onCreate` I have:

```
currentType = (String) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
```

And then:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    final String s = currentType;
    return s;
}
```

It works fine if the orientation doesn't change and then change back again quickly.  I'd like to fix this though because department and retail stores are using/will use this and I can see people dropping it, which will cause an FC (dropped it on my couch to test).  I'm only storing one string so what I'm storing doesn't take up much memory.  Any suggestions for this new situation?

Comment: What is getLastNonConfigInst? Doesn't that method return like a bundle or a map not a String? So you would have to get it out of it first

Comment: Yes it does return an Object but I casted it to String in the above example

Comment: wait, where are you setting currentType?  It looks like it's a class field, and I see you're setting it in the constructor, but I don't wee where you're actually ever setting it to a non-null string? In other words, what is the value when onRetainNonConfigurationInstance is called?

Comment: I set the string depending on what type of QR code is scanned with the app in another method.  When `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` is called `currentType` is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this working somewhat like I wanted. There was a statement buried in a method that set currentType to null towards the end of the life cycle when the variable wouldn't be needed again. That's now out of the way. The screen will successfully change orientations but if it's changed between the two successively too quickly it will FC. This is what I used to get it working in this state:

Class Field:

```
private String currentType;
```

At the end of onCreate I have:

```
currentType = (String) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
```

And then:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    final String s = currentType;
    return s;
}
```

It works fine if the orientation doesn't change and then change back again quickly.  Asking new question about this new bug,

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting it in a Bundle?

```
private static final String CURRENT_TYPE = "currentType";
private static final String DEFAULT_TYPE = "defaultType";
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
  outState.putString(CURRENT_TYPE, currentType);
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  currentType = (savedInstanceState == null)? null : 
        savedInstanceState.getString(CURRENT_TYPE, DEFAULT_TYPE);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have, I stated that at the beginning of my post.  I just tried it again with your example, but included `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)` and `super.onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and had no luck again

Comment: Good catch, there should be super calls. Also, onRestoreInstanceState is called after onStart. It's usually better to restore state in onCreate instead (hence, edit).

Comment: I just tried with your edited suggestion and I was getting an FC on launch.  Not sure why, `currentType` is a class variable, maybe since there was no `savedInstanceState` on launch?

Comment: Yeah, it's null on the first call. Sorry about that.